# Zeros of elements of $C\{M_n\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $M_0,M_1,\ldots$ be positive constants and $C\{M_n\}$ be the class of all infinitely differentiable functions $f$ on the real axis such that the inequalities
\begin{equation}
|f^{(n)}(x)| \le \beta_fB_f^nM_n.
\end{equation} holds for all $x \in R$ and $n=01,2,\ldots$, where $\beta_f$ and $B_f$ are positive constants. We say $C\{M_n\}$ is quasi-analytic if the condition $f \in C\{M_n\}$ satisfies $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ will imply $f(x)=0$ on the real axis. I wonder the existence of a function $f$ of this class which has infinitely many zeros on a bounded interval. Any comments? Thanks!

Comment: You should add a definition of $C\{M_n\}$. You just explained that if all derivatives vanish, then the function vanishes. But this does not define what is means for $f$ to be an element of $C\{M_n\}$.

Comment: @Markmeister, Thanks for your reminder. I have just added the definition of $C\{M_n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has infinitely many zeroes on a bounded interval $I$, then by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem the set of zeroes has an accumulation point $x_0\in I$. I claim that $f^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$ for all nonnegative integers $n$. Indeed, if there is a sequence of distinct points $x_n\to x_0$ with $f(x_n)=0$, then by Rolle's theorem we can obtain a sequence $c_n$ of distinct points between the $x_n$'s such that $c_n\to x_0$ as $n\to\infty$ and also $f'(c_n)=0$. Thus $f'(x_0)=0$ by continuity. Inductively replacing $f$ with $f^{(k)}$ in this argument proves the claim.

Since $C\{M_n\}$ is a quasianalytic class, $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ for all $n$ implies $f\equiv 0$ identically. Hence the only function in $C\{M_n\}$ with infinitely many zeroes in a bounded interval is the constant $0$ function.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you!